# Working bookmark script for iphone/smartphones

Tags: javascript, iphone, smartphone, bookmarks

Can you use a script on your page with the "bookmark us" url on a smartphone? I know Chrome doesn't support this function but i was wondering if there is a way to get it working on an iphone?

Cheers,

Toby

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is unfortunately no way to do this in code on iOS.

The suggested route is to prompt the user to add your website as a bookmark.

To do this, there is a neat little JS library: [mobile-bookmark-bubble](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/).